# PassportJS with express (nodejs) upload form

Tags: node.js, express, upload, passport.js

I want to make a upload form. This part is done and it work... but now I want to put the same security authentification that I have already in my project.

I Have this:

```
 app.post('/me/profile/picture/upload',function(req, res){

    req.form.on('part', function(part){
        // transfer to s3 etc
        console.log('upload %s %s', part.name, part.filename);
        var out = fs.createWriteStream(tempUploadPath + part.filename);
        part.pipe(out);
    });

    req.form.on('close', function(){
        res.respond("Success!", 200);
    });

});
```

but I want this:

```
    app.post('/me/profile/picture/upload', passportToken.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),function(req, res){

    req.form.on('part', function(part){
        // transfer to s3 etc
        console.log('upload %s %s', part.name, part.filename);
        var out = fs.createWriteStream(tempUploadPath + part.filename);
        part.pipe(out);
    });

    req.form.on('close', function(){
        res.respond("Success!", 200);
    });

});
```

But when I add this passport code it freeze when transfering the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly resolved !

Need to add this:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({
    keepExtensions: true,
    uploadDir: __dirname + '/tmp',
    limit: '20mb'
}));

// Create our own middleware constructor.
var bufferedAuthenticate = function(){

    // Set up standard authenticate handler passing arguments through.
    var authMiddleware = passportToken.authenticate.apply(passportToken, arguments);

    // Pass our own middleware instead that wraps passport-http.
    return function(req, res, next){

        // Pause the request before authenticating.
        var obj = pause(req);
        authMiddleware(req, res, function(err){
            next(err);

            // Emit any cached data events that fired while authenticating.
            obj.resume();
        });
    };
};

app.post('/me/profile/picture/upload',  bufferedAuthenticate('bearer', { session: false }), function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);

    if (req.files.qqfile) {
        var exists = fs.existsSync(req.files.qqfile.path);
        fs.rename(req.files.qqfile.path, "tmp/" + req.files.qqfile.name, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(">> Error!: " + err);
                res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: err }), { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }, 200);
            }
            else {
                console.log('File Uploaded! ' + "tmp/" + req.files.qqfile.name);
                res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true }), { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }, 200);
            }});
    } else {
        res.send(JSON.stringify({ success: false, error: "No file sent!" }, { "Content-type": "application/json" }, 200));
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback recieves a request and response object as parameter. You have to pass these to the authentication function. Try something like this:

```
app.post('/me/profile/picture/upload', function (req, res) {

    passportToken.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), function(){

        req.form.on('part', function(part){
            // transfer to s3 etc
            console.log('upload %s %s', part.name, part.filename);
            var out = fs.createWriteStream(tempUploadPath + part.filename);
            part.pipe(out);
        });

        req.form.on('close', function(){
            res.respond("Success!", 200);
        });

    })(req, res)

});
```

Comment: doesn't work .. :( same trouble (freeze).. there is a typo error. " session: false }), --->  session: false },"